# enums with same integer value in select statement in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

How can the following be coded so that it compiles in `C#`?  The compiler error is: `the label 'case 3:' already occurs in this switch statement`.

```
switch (customerType)
{
    case CustomerType.Private:
        return externCustomerType.P;
    case CustomerType.Business:
        return externCustomerType.B;
    case CustomerType.Interstate:
    case CustomerType.Overseas:
        return externCustomerType.I;
    default:
        return externCustomerType.N;
}

public enum CustomerType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Private = 1,
    Business = 2,
    Interstate = 3,
    Overseas = 3
}
```

Comment: remove the comma behind Overseas = 3? and cast your enums to int? case (int) CustomerType.Private: ...

Comment: are you added the Integers for a specific reason? if not just remove them! oh.... and the last comma as @failedprogramming mentioned!

Comment: See my edit.  I have fixed that typo.  The error is actually because of the last two enum values having the same integer value.

Comment: If `Interstate` and `Overseas` have the same value, a customer type cannot be one without also being the other. You can simply remove one of the case labels.

Comment: @MPatel: The enum definition cannot be changed - it is being used by other code.

Comment: @hvd: that is not satisfactory to me because if someone changes the integer values of the enum type then my code will break.

Comment: @CJ7 Indeed, but changing the enumeration should already be treated as a breaking change, and you do treat it as such with regards to other code. There are various ways to make sure that your code gives a compile-time error if the enumeration definition changes, which would catch any breakage very early, which would avoid any incorrect run-time behaviour.

Comment: @CJ7 For example, see http://ideone.com/OkzUWY. Change the enumeration so that `C` and `D` have different values, and you get a  compiler error.

Answer (score 8):

It's enough to do

```
switch (customerType)
{
    case CustomerType.Private:
        return externCustomerType.P;
    case CustomerType.Business:
        return externCustomerType.B;
    case CustomerType.Interstate:
        return externCustomerType.I;
    default:
        return externCustomerType.N;
}
```

As both `Overseas` and `Interstate` have value of 3 so it will work if `customerType` has either of the values (as in fact it has just a value of 3, you just assign the same integer value using a different enum values).

---

If you want to be independent of the values of the enum, rewrite your `switch` as `if`s:

```
if (customerType == CustomerType.Private)
    return externCustomerType.P;
else if (customerType == CustomerType.Business)
    return externCustomerType.B;
else if (customerType == CustomerType.Overseas || customerType == CustomerType.Interstate)
    return externCustomerType.I;
else 
    return externCustomerType.N;
```

Comment: That is not satisfactory to me because if someone changes the integer values of the enum type then my code will break.

Comment: @CJ7 OK, another solution for you then, see my update.